# Remove Google Font "Mulish" from Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, google-font-api, google-fonts

I'm working on a custom theme that doesn't add any Google Fonts but I noticed that Wordpress add the font **Mulish** by default.
For privacy reasons I want to remove it.

[image]

I already tried via code with no success

```
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', function($href) {
    if(strpos($href, "https://fonts.googleapis.com/") === false) {
        return $href;
    }
    return false;
});
```

and also [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-remove-google-fonts/#description) doesn't remove it.

How can do it?

Comment: I think WordPress doesn't add 'Mulish' font by default.

Answer (score 0):

Find the solution myself: the Mulish font was added by the Chrome extension “Pop up blocker for Chrome™ – Poper Blocker”. Just disable it to see.

So remember that your browser extensions modify the DOM of your websites, for example just adding Google Fonts.